# Implementing Timeout Javascript in a PeopleSoft iScript

Tags: peoplesoft

Regular PeopleSoft components automatically generate a timeout popup window when a user is about to be logged out.  iScripts, however, do not.

I was about to reverse-engineer the javascript that PeopleSoft automatically generates for components in order to leverage existing code.

Before I do, I thought I'd check if anyone else has done this, and if there are any gotchas, tips or tricks.  Or maybe there's a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reverse engineered how the Navigation Collections page (which is an iScript) works since it also handles timeouts.   The solution is relatively simple.

First, include the results of %Request.ExpireMeta (PeopleCode function) in the  portion of the HTML you generate.

Secondly, include the delivered javascript PT_SAVEWARNINGSCRIPT in the HTML you generate.

Finally, have your iScript call the javascript function setupTimeout().